# SOLR query specifying several values

Tags: solr, wildcard

I am doing a solar query.  With my filter I want to look for various values of x (1004, 1005, 1006).  I tried using  x:100[456] but it did not like that.  I did a search in google and found some information but not how to do this.  I remember seeing someone else do something similar a few weeks ago but I cannot remember what it was.  What would be the correct syntax?  I suppose I could figure out how to do an OR if the number of them was small enough.

Comment: I should add I do NOT want 1007

Comment: did you tried something like this..fq=x:(1004+OR+1005+OR+1006)

Comment: Probably the [FingerprintFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-FingerprintFilter) is worth a look. Depends on your Use Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a range query, the solr syntax is:

```
x:[1004 TO 1006]
```

Comment: See I did try that before but I got the following:

Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '+x:[1004 to 1006]': Encountered " <RANGE_GOOP> "1006 "" at line 1, column 42.
Was expecting one of:
    "]" ...
    "}" ...

I also tried without the "+" but same thing

Comment: use capitals for the `TO`